# Can't Compile Using GCD function calls

Tags: macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to compile a Desktop OS X Cocoa application:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSLog(@"Hello World"); });
```

However, I am getting the following compile time error:

implicit declaration of function dispatch_sync

I have imported these lines:

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#import <dispatch/queue.h>
#import <dispatch/base.h>
```

The Base SDK is set to 10.6. Anything else to look for? Am I missing an import?

Any ideas?

Comment: The only import you need is `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` which I suspect you already have. Otherwise as Colin answer says, check your deployment target.

Answer (score 5):

hmm, you shouldn't need to do anything as GCD is part of libSystem and thus should get it for free. Have you set your deployment target to something earlier than 10.6?

Comment: The deployment target is 10.6. Turns out the project was using GCC 4.0. As soon as I went to LLVM GCC 4.2 I was able to use GCD. Thanks

Comment: ah that would explain it as well, didn't even think about the compiler being an issue. Glad you found the cause of it.

Comment: Do you know when libSystem is linked?

Answer (score 0):

Had to make sure compiler was set to LLVM GCC 4.2 (was GCC 4.0)